# How to disable Link for some time after being clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

To prevent impatient users from clicking on a link to a webstart application too often, I tried to disable the hyperlink for some seconds after it has been called the first time.

```
<a href="file.jnlp" onclick="if (!this.clicked){this.clicked = true; setTimeout('this.clicked = false' ,10000); return true;} return false">
```

The code above only works for disabling the link, but it doesn't get re-enabled after the timeout of 10 seconds.

I've seen that the 'this.clicked' variable isn't true (as it is supposed to be) when I check it in the setTimeout call. Maybe i'm missing some basic JS-knowledge here..

Or perhaps there is a different approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to use functions instead of doing everything inline.. it will be easier to debug the code.

Also, consider learning JQuery. It would make it a lot easier to add a visual effect to the "disabling" of the link.

Comment: I don't like inline code either, but I'm working in some JSF-view, and I must admit, I don't know how and where to declare a JS-Function there. But that's another story, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this anchor an ID and then change your timeout call to:

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById("<id>").clicked = false;' , 10000);
```

I think the 'this' is not evaluated to anything when the timer comes around.

Answer (score 3):

First add a this function to a Javascript Script block

```
function Debounce()
{

    var self = this
    if (this.clicked) return false;

    this.clicked = true;
    setTimeout(function() {self.clicked = false;}, 10000);

    return true;
}
```

Now change your onclick to:-

```
onclick="return Debounce.call(this)"
```

Answer (score 2):

using your code modifying only a small part it may work

```
<a href="file.jnlp" onclick="if (!this.clicked){this.clicked = true; setTimeout(function(){this.clicked = false;} ,10000); return true;} return false">
```

looks like people say that didnt work and it didnt form a closure around 'this'

Comment: yeah, nice too :) basically the problem was with the 'this' being a string. this way it's actually an object

Comment: Note though that 'this' when using inside the function invoked by setTimeout will be the window (the global object) not the anchor element its intended to be.

Comment: didn't work. the 'this' seems to be the problem, as MasterPeter assumed

Answer (score 2):

The `this` object is not defined in the code being evaluated by `setTimeout` which is done in the global scope.

Give the link an ID then use `getElementById` e.g.

```
<a href="file.jnlp" id='my_link' onclick="if(!this.clicked){this.clicked = true; setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'my_link\').clicked = false;' ,10000); return true;} return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=this;
setTimeout(function(){a.clicked = false} ,10000);
```

Comment: +1. That'll do it but the attribute content is getting overly complex especially since it could be formulated as a re-usable function for use on other links

Comment: yeah, lot of stuff going on in that attribute